# Why females don't have much sexual desire when compare to males?

Tags: human-biology, sex

I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playgirl) Wikipedia article about Playgirl, It is made especially for females. but Its Spokesman Daniel Nardico revealed subscriptions are generated **more from males**.

> In a February 2010 interview with the Associated Press, Playgirl
>   spokesman Daniel Nardico stated that he considers the magazine
>   appealing to both men and women, although the audience is
>   predominantly **male**

I found another source [here](https://kinseyconfidential.org/men-sex-women/) to claim,

> - They did not find a single study that showed that women had a higher    sex drive than men.
> - But **Majority** found that men had higher drive than women.

Why females don't have much sexual desire when compare to males?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. In order to ask `Why`, one must first show that the claim is true or instead start by asking whether the claim is true, otherwise the question must be closed as opinion-based. I am afraid that a wikipedia article about Playgirl reporting an interview with a nightlife impressario is most definitely not an evidence that females have less sexual desire than males. I am voting to close as off-topic because it is opinion-based

Comment: In fact, if you just google [Do females have more sexual desires than males?](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+female+have+as+much+sexual+desires+than+males%3F&oq=do+female+have+as+much+sexual+desires+than+males%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.9478j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you'll get plenty of hits like [this one](http://webcenters.netscape.compuserve.com/whatsnew/package.jsp?name=fte/10sexmyths/10sexmyths), which although they don't cite a peer review paper rather suggest that your claim is wrong.

Comment: Where did you get the hypothesis from that more male subscribers for a magazine equals less sexual desire for females?

Comment: @Remi.b I added another source link to claim it, still is it **closed**?

Comment: Males often have more desire from a distance, but up close they turn cold. The opposite applies to females.

Comment: @The two added quotation seem to come in opposition.... I am definitely not convince yet that it would be true that females have less sexual desires than males.